# Uso del WHERE NOT IN en Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

Quiero obtener los libros sin repetir que hay en la tabla libro pero si no están ya añadidos a la tabla lineapedido con el cliente que está realizando la consulta. En vez de eso, con el siguiente código obtengo los libros que hay en la tabla lineapedido que por supuesto, están repetidos.

```
$libros=DB::table('libro as l')
            ->join('autor as a', 'l.lib_autor_id', '=', 'a.id_autor')
            ->join('generoartistico as ga', 'ga.id_generoartistico', '=', 'a.atr_genero_artistico_id')
            ->join('generoliterario as gl', 'gl.id_generoliterario', '=', 'l.lib_genero_literario_id')
            ->join('lineapedido as lp', 'lp.lpe_libro_id', '=', 'l.id_libro')
            ->join('pedido as ped', 'ped.id_pedido', '=', 'lp.lpe_pedido_id')
            ->join('cliente as cli', 'cli.id_cliente', '=', 'ped.ped_cliente_id')
            ->select('l.id_libro', 'l.lib_no', 'l.lib_titulo', 'l.lib_direccion_web', 'l.lib_fecha_creacion',
                'l.lib_precio','l.lib_activo','a.atr_nombre_artistico as autor', 'gl.gl_nombre as generoliterario',
                'ga.ga_nombre as generoartistico', 'a.id_autor')
            ->when($filteredQuery, function($q) use ($query, $gArt, $gLit, $usuario_actual){
                        $q->where('lib_titulo', 'LIKE', '%'. $query . '%');
                        $q->where('id_generoartistico', '=', $gArt);
                        $q->where('id_generoliterario', '=', $gLit);
                        $q->where('lib_activo', '=', '1');
                        $q->whereNotIn('id_cliente', function($query){
                            $query->select('ped_cliente_id')->from('pedido');

                        });

                    })->get();
```

Esta sería la query que querría:

```
 SELECT `libro`.*, `autor`.`atr_nombre_artistico`, `generoartistico`.`ga_nombre`, `generoliterario`.`gl_nombre` 
FROM `libro` 
INNER JOIN `autor` ON `autor`.`id_autor`=`libro`.`lib_autor_id` 
INNER JOIN `generoartistico` ON `generoartistico`.`id_generoartistico`=`autor`.`atr_genero_artistico_id` 
INNER JOIN `generoliterario` ON `generoliterario`.`id_generoliterario`=`libro`.`lib_genero_literario_id` 
INNER JOIN `lineapedido` ON `lineapedido`.`lpe_libro_id`=`libro`.`id_libro` 
INNER JOIN `pedido` ON `pedido`.`id_pedido`=`lineapedido`.`lpe_pedido_id` 
INNER JOIN `cliente` ON `cliente`.`id_cliente`=`pedido`.`ped_cliente_id` 
WHERE $usuario_actual->u_cliente_id NOT IN (SELECT `pedido`.`ped_cliente_id` FROM `pedido`) 
GROUP BY `libro`.`id_libro`;
```

¿Alguien sabría como hay que poner esa consulta en laravel?

Comment: ¿puedes mostrar la query que genera Laravel?

Answer (score 0):

una opción a considerar podría ser la siguiente:

```php
$pedidos = DB::table('pedido')->select('pedido.ped_cliente_id')->get()->toArray();
$pedidos_array = collect($pedidos)->map(function($x){ return (array) $x; })->toArray(); 

DB::table('libro')
->join('autor','autor.id_autor','=','libro.lib_autor_id')
->join('generoartistico','generoartistico.id_generoartistico','=','autor.generoartistico.')
->join('generoliterario','generoliterario.id_generoliterario','=','libro.lib_genero_literario_id')
->join('lineapedido','lineapedido.lpe_libro_id','=','libro.id_libro')
->join('pedido','pedido.id_pedido','=','lineapedido.lpe_pedido_id')
->join('cliente','cliente.id_cliente','=','pedido.ped_cliente_id')
->whereNotIn($usuario_actual->u_cliente_id, $pedidos_array)
->groupBy('libro.id_libro')
->select('libro.*','autor.atr_nombre_artistico','generoartistico.ga_nombre','generoliterario.gl_nombre')
->get();
```

Algo que de igual forma puedes utilizar al generar este tipo de consultas complejas para validar se está generando el query esperado, es colocar antes de la consulta un `DB::enableQueryLog();` y colocando al final del query un `dd(DB::getQueryLog());`.